# Google Drive to Sheet File Data Iteration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I found this very useful script on here for iteratively returning a list of file metrics by directory in GDrive. My problem is I want to add columns that exclude emails from a give domain. For example on the `fileItem.getEditors` I might want to return a list excluding editors in the "@mycompany.com" domain.

```
var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
var childFiles = parent.getFiles();
var allValues = []; // Added
while (childFiles.hasNext()){
  var fileItem = childFiles.next();
  data = [
    parentName + "/" + fileItem.getName() + "/" + fileItem.getName(),
    fileItem.getName(),
    fileItem.getMimeType(),
    fileItem.getUrl(),
    fileItem.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
    fileItem.getSharingPermission(),
    fileItem.isShareableByEditors(),
    fileItem.getOwner().getEmail(),
    fileItem.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
    fileItem.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
  ];
  allValues.push(data); // Added
}
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, allValues.length, allValues[0].length).setValues(allValues); // Added
```

Comment: `fileItem.getEditors().filter(e => e.getDomain() != "@mycompany.com").map(e => { return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()] }).join(",")`

Comment: Fantastic answer. The issue with this is it seems to yield a list of those containing @mycompany.com and I need a list of those NOT containing it. I'm having trouble altering it appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps you did not copy it correctly it should have a list of those domains not equal to your domain.  In any event changing the == to != or changing the != to == should do the trick

Comment: right you are. This works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cooper's answer is already great but you don't need to include `@` on the comparison.

Filter your data by adding `filter` before the `map` that gets the email and name:

```
.filter(function(e){e.getDomain() != "mycompany.com"})
```

Output:

```
fileItem.getEditors().filter(function(e){e.getDomain() != "mycompany.com"})
                     .map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
```

Comment: It should only include those domains that are not *mycompany.com* as we are filtering it using `!=`. Let's chat over [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239888/room-for-nazia-and-w-lyman) @W.Lyman for more info

Comment: This actually doesn't appear to yield anything for me.

Comment: I actually prefer this format to the abbreviated function language cooper graciously provided but try as I might to get it to work it just doesn't yield anything.

Comment: @W.Lyman, I wonder why it doesn't yield anything. Does Cooper's abbreviated answer work? As for me it is working the same as coopers output. Properly excludes the email with the domain mentioned above. (as long as you are using `!=`)